# Yii Ejuidatetimepicker

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datetime, yii

I have an entry module for user's shift which you have to set the start and end time of shift.

The website is now being used in Vietnam. I'm using `EJuiDateTimePicker` for the selection of start and end time.

The problem is that `am` is `sa` and `pm` is `ch`.

Now when my action read the values using my model, what I retrieve is like these:

- for start time - 1:30 ch (which is 1:30 pm supposedly)
- for end time - 2:30 ch (which is 2:30 pm supposedly)

and when I hit save, I received this error:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (03:45 ch) at position 6 (c): The timezone could not be found in the database
```

My timeformat for the picker is `hh:mm tt`.

Is there a way for me to retrieve the times in `am` or `pm` not in `sa` or `ch`? or a way where I can convert the time I retrieved to `am` or `pm`?

Comment: the time I entered was 3:45 ch for the start time and 5:45 ch for the end time actually.